# c99 Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, incomplete-type

I have this in input_lib.c:

```
#include "input_lib.h"

struct edge {
    int from;
    int to;
};
```

input_lib.h contains my typedef:

```
typedef struct edge edge;
```

Then in another file which includes `input_lib.h`, I declare a variable and attempt to use it:

```
edge *my_edge = read_next_edge();
printf("%d, %d", my_edge->from, my_edge->to);
```

I get the error at the `printf` line:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

read_next_edge() returns an edge* that is allocated by:

```
edge *next_edge = malloc(sizeof(struct edge));
```

My C is a little rusty so I assume I've just made a small mistake somewhere, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out where. I would really appreciate if someone could explain where my mistake is, and why I'm getting it. Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same problem as [Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609940/dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting to access the internals of the structure outside of `input_lib.c`, then the structure definition needs to be in `input_lib.h`.  If you are expecting code outside of `input_lib.c` to use access functions to get at the information, then you can leave the structure opaque (incomplete) but you need to call the functions to get the information.

Either way works; choose one and stick with it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `struct` definition should be in `input_lib.h`